# Run sudo su and tcsh from a script to change the terminal

Tags: sudo, tcsh

Whenever I putty into one of our Linux VMs, I run:

```
sudo su - serviceid
tcsh
bindkey -k up history-search-backward
bindkey -k down history-search-forward
```

The serviceid changes depending on what server I am connecting to.  I'd like to automate the process such that it looks at `uname -n` to pick what serviceid to use.

A script most likely wouldn't work as it would apply to the script itself and not the terminal that calls the script.

The serviceids are shared so no change can be made to /home/serviceid/

How can script a change to the terminal?

Comment: If you want to execute this on multiple servers, the easiest way would be to use expect: https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect . An alternative could be to change the default shell for each of the serviceid accounts to `tcsh` instead of `bash`, and put the bindkey commands into `~/.tcshrc` file. Why can't you login via PuTTY directly to the serviceid account, but use `sudo su` to change into it instead?

Comment: I cannot log in with the serviceid account as I do not have the password and sudo su is the approach dictated by the company.  I cannot edit the /home/serviceid/.tcshrc file as that would be the for the serviceid and this is a UAT environment that must match PROD.  I have a user folder that I start at for all of these machines.  I'd like to run something from my user folder that elevates me and switches to tcsh while remaining on the Terminal prompt.

Comment: So you can try with expect. Or you can use KiTTY instead of PuTTY and its "login script" feature. But you have to prepare a separate login script for each serviceid name (a separate KiTTY session for each server).

Comment: KiTTY worked.  I have a script that echoes the service id for each server and call sudo su - `./GetServiceId.sh`.  Thanks.